# Searching Sharepoint/Access - Update table

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2007

I have been working on a sharepoint search tool.  I know very little about sharepoint so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

I have a number of tables on a sharepoint site. One of the tables contains the "People" in the database. I have the ability to view this table as a linked table using access, but my coworkers do not have the permissions to do so. My way around it was to use a make table query insert a table into a shared folder and give them read only front end in access to search for the client and when they find them open up a hyperlink to the person on sharepoint. The search feature works great, but I have to manually update the local table (using make table) (which I am not able to do if someone is using the search).

As I see it there are two ways I might be able to solve this, but I am open to any ideas I am by no means an expert:

Is there a better way to search in sharepoint? - I am hoping to have something where they are able to enter in a first name last name dob etc and find the results that match the fields and allow a partial match (so if some fields aren't entered they are ignored). I have not found anything that was able to help me do this, but I do not know what it would be called so if you know what I should look into I would greatly appreciate it!

Is there a way to update the table in Access while someone is using it? Is there another way to accomplish this in access?

What direction do you think I should take? I am usually able to find the information I need online, but I have not had too much success with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://root site URL/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx

This syntax will get you to your hidden user content type list on a SP 2010 site - and you can change the view on this to give you different fields.  I haven't yet found a way for this to link to anything that gives me site/list/library access rights, but have found it EXTREMELY useful in place of anything approaching a third party central user administration tool. - You might be able to do something with this for what you're trying to do.